# Ajax calls behind a firewall and a proxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm working on application with .NET MVC3 and Ajax (JQuery).

My application works fine when the clients work with a direct internet connection. but there are some clients working behind a proxy and a firewall.

The application works fine at the begining but after some changes the ajax calls return null from time to time.

i have no idea about this problem. is it the ajax calls that fails or maybe the firewalls block some ajax calls ?

Thanks,

Comment: Any chance your requests are being sent to a non-standard port?

Comment: Thanks, My resquests are sent via the 8080 port. But i have done some tests by changing the port to 80. the client had the same problem.

Comment: Gotchya. I had a similar problem doing the exact same thing about a year ago - but changing from 8080 back to 80 worked for me.

Maybe the client had a cached version that was still asking for 8080 when you switched? Clients lie ALL THE TIME about clearing their cache.

Comment: Thanks Kennis. there are many clients not one !!

Comment: I am struggling on the similar issue (AJAX calls behind a proxy).. proxy servers blocks my AJAX call requests. Any solution to fix this issue?